# API response is not in proper JSON form instead an array

Tags: php

As given in the title, when I tried to open a page with holiday list nothing is open up, and when I check my API response it is in the form of array, instead of JSON.

My API function:

```
public static function API_getYearHolidays($year = false) {  //API
    if ($year == false) {
        $year = date('Y', time());
    }
    $q = "SELECT * FROM holidays";
    $runQuery = self::DBrunQuery($q);
    $rows = self::DBfetchRows($runQuery);
    $list = array();

    if ($year == false) {
        $list = $rows;
    } else {
        foreach ($rows as $pp) {
            $h_date = $pp['date'];
            $h_year = date('Y', strtotime($h_date));
            if ($h_year == $year) {
                $list[] = $pp;
            }
        }
    }

    if (sizeof($list) > 0) {
        foreach ($list as $key => $v) {
            $list[$key]['month'] = date('F', strtotime($v['date']));
            $list[$key]['dayOfWeek'] = date('l', 
    strtotime($v['date']));
        }
    }


    $r_error = 0;
    $return = array();
    $return['error'] = $r_error;
    $r_data['message'] = "";
    $r_data['holidays'] = $list;
    $return['data'] = $r_data;
    print_r($return) ;
    return json_encode($return);
}
```

My *api.php* file which is calling the API function:

```
if ($action == "get_holidays_list") {
$res = HR::API_getYearHolidays();
echo $res;
```

My API response:

```
Array
(
[error] => 0
[data] => Array
    (
        [message] => 
        [holidays] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 87
                        [name] => New Year
                        [date] => 2018-01-01
                        [month] => January
                        [dayOfWeek] => Monday
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 88
                        [name] => Republic Day
                        [date] => 2018-01-26
                        [month] => January
                        [dayOfWeek] => Friday
                    ))))
```

and nothing is shown in the browser. Please help me find the error in the function.

Comment: Why did you use `return` in api.php ? It is in method ?

Comment: yes! sorry, my mistake. i've changed it back to 'echo $res;'

Comment: but still getting 'false' in api response

Comment: So now your question is you getting empty from API function ?

Comment: yes. empty from api function.

Comment: Can you please remove `print_r($return) ;` from API function and give us your output.

Comment: yes i did that. and getting 'false' as response.

Comment: You need to do debug your API function. And before that please check API function call or not ?

Comment: {"error":0,"data":{"id":"31333","name":"Vimal Kumar","email":"vimal@example.in"}} - this is the api response from other functions. i want this function to generate this type of json data.

Comment: You did that ? If yes, please explain what is actual problem ?

Comment: There must be some error is API_getYearHolidays() function because other functions called by _api.php_ working just fine, except this one.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have debug code here, before return statement in function `API_getYearHolidays`:

```
print_r($return) ;
```

Either comment it or delete it and check again.

**EDIT:**
Nothing is printed in script, use echo instead of return in function call in api.php

```
if ($action == "get_holidays_list") {
    $res = HR::API_getYearHolidays();
    echo $res;
```

Comment: i did that, but then no response is generated

Comment: response is "false"

Comment: did that. but response is still 'false'